# Minimizing Content on Blog Homepage Feed

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, design, interface

When I say blog homepage feed I mean the whole wordpress frontpage where the title and all or just part of the blog articles are displayed. 
My question is if having a little clickable minimize (or minus symbol) thing by the title to display the content or minimize the content would be good for the user or not because I've never seem it managed in this way. 
Basically the title is a link but there is another button or method to maximize and minimize the content of the article

Comment: What you are asking is dependant on a lot of other factors such as who your users are, what they want to get from the site, what content you're minimising, etc. Most Wordpress sites i have seen tend to show truncated versions of articles on the front page which invites the user to move to the article page to read more. I doubt that expanding one of those articles in place on the front page would serve any purpose but, like I said, it depends on a whole lot of other things.

Comment: Agreed with Andrew Martin. If we were, however, to generalize and speculate, the question could be boiled down to  "Is it more valuable in general to have minimized content than to not have it?" If it's not, then it's not worth the work. There are obvious value points in having truncated articles. i.e. Adds to the information in the headline, sets expectation of the writing style, gives the page more structural substance (making it easier to design for). What are the value points for having minimized content?